# MongoDB storing one day before than actual date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am facing one issue to store the actual date(01/08/2018) that what I passed from model. My document is stored successfully but MongoDB store the one day before than what I passed in model.

Here I am passing the date(dd/MM/yyyy) is **01/08/2018**

For more detail please check the below snaps.

[image]

After successfully saved the record, I checked in Robo 3T(MongoDB) and I show that it stored the one day before than actual value. Stored date is **2018-07-31**. For more detail please see the below snap.

[image]

I hope so might be issue with timezone or offset but I don't know what is the solution.

Comment: Yes mongodb stores the dates a day less from actual one but when you will retrieve your data it will be again with same day

Answer (score 1):

By using Moment Library https://momentjs.com/ your issue can be solved. you have to just passed a date like below and follow the format.

```
var myDate = new Date(moment("2018-07-04").format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
```

save this to you DB it will work